# Testing significance: single population, two-sample unpaired data

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, sample, two-sample

I am looking to test the significance of a training/ education program of home building construction. I am working with unpaired data of a dependent sample and am unsure how to proceed. Since the design of the study was to understand building code compliance of new construction, the data points could only be collected once from a home and were sampled independent of the builder.

In phase 1, a set of data points were collected from a randomly selected sample of homes. The data points are individual building code compliance measures, so can be both continuous and categorical (For example: air leakage rate, insulation level, duct air tightness). Home builders were given education/ training in an effort to improve compliance. Following the same methodology in phase 1, a second sampling of data was collected.

I want to test if the training/ education had a significant impact on building measures. Instead of comparing pre and post training, I could alternatively compare each sample to the baseline compliance level. What significance test should I be considering? I appreciate any support that can be given.

Comment: What about a [permutation test][1] of whether the mean scores of the second sampling and first sampling are the same? That would require you to come up with some way of scoring each individual building's measures into a single number though.


  [1]: https://thomasleeper.com/Rcourse/Tutorials/permutationtests.html

Comment: About how many homes before & after? Dozens? hundreds? // How many 'individual compliance measures" are there? Suppose the answer is $k.$ Can you combine all $k$ into a single numerical score for each home? // Or would you have to compare before and after samples for each of the $k$ measures separately? If this case you may need different kinds of tests for 'categorical' measures and 'continuous' ones. Would be helpful if, for each measure, you could give examples of values for several homes, with an indication of possible values for categorical and max and min values for continuous.

Comment: So each individual measure had 64 homes before and 64 after. Unfortunately the measures could not be combined into a single score. Certain measures were taken at various stages of the construction process (ie. once the walls are finished we cant see insulation levels) so all measures could not be taken from a single home. Continues measurements include air leakage (in f3/m). A categorical variable would be wall insulation (R-15, R-13, etc.). Another possibility would be to test the variance of the before and after to the compliance level.